# Measure of a convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $x_k \in R^n, k=1,2,3...$ be a convergent sequence. Show that the measure of $ \{x_k | k \in N\}$ is 0.

I separated the points and made the measure equal to the sum of the measure of each point which is 0. But I don’t see why is the convergence needed

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know anything about the measure of a countable set?

Comment: A countable set has Lebesgue measure $0$.

Comment: @cmk I separated the points and made the measure equal to the sum of the measure of each point which is 0. But I don’t see why is the convergence needed.

Comment: Either this is a trick question (see Surb's comment) in which one of the hypotheses is unnecessary, or perhaps you've misread it. Could it be that the thing whose measure you're supposed to examine is $\overline{\{x_k | k \in N\}}$ instead (i.e., the closure of the set you wrote down)?

Comment: No, the question is correct. I think it just might be a trick question! Thanks

Comment: By the way, welcome to MSE. It's a good idea, when you pose a question like this, to include what you've already tried (as you did in your comment to @cmk); that saves folks like PierreCarre from writing down answers that needn't have been written. You can edit your question by clicking "edit" just beneath the question itself.

Comment: You might be seeing this question again, in a later chapter, with that "overline" -- it'd make a nice followup question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use $\sigma$-additivity:

$$
\mu(\{x_k | k \in \mathbb{N}\} = \mu \left(\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \{x_k\}\right) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \mu(\{x_k\}) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} 0 = 0
$$

The fact that the sequence is convergent is irrelevant.